# Show the array in the Inspector (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inspector

I have a list of arrays that I want to show in the inspector

This is my code:

```
        SerializedProperty ClipArray;
        ClipArray = serializedObject.FindProperty("ClipArray"); // public AudioClip[] ClipArray;



        serializedObject.Update();
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(ClipArray);
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
```

But in the inspector, I show an array without parameters

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried putting system serializable above the script when you declare your array?

```
[System.Serializable]
public AudioClip[] ClipArray;
```

Are any of the values in your array initially set to null?

Comment: the attribute [`[Serializable]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.serializableattribute) only applies to **types** so e.g. a `class` or `struct` and is not used on individual fields. What you ment was probably Unity's [`[SerializeField]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html), though a public field is serialized anyway (if according type is Serializable). The type `AudioClip` already **is** serializable.

Answer (score 1):

This is a quite known issue with arrays/lists in custom Editors.

If you checkout [`EditorGUILayout.PropertyField`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.PropertyField.html) you will see there are overloads taking a parameter

> **includeChildren**
>   
>  If `true` the property including children is drawn; **otherwise only the control itself (such as only a foldout but nothing below it)**.

so actually all you need to do is passing `true` like

```
SerializedProperty ClipArray;

// I would always do these only once ;)
private void OnEnable()
{
    ClipArray = serializedObject.FindProperty("ClipArray");
}

private void OnInspectorGUI ()
{
    serializedObject.Update();
    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(ClipArray, true);
    serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
}
```

---

As an alternative you could ofcourse also build the entire draw hierachy with the required fields yourself:

```
private void OnInspectorGUI ()
{
    serializedObject.Update();

    ClipArray.isExpanded = EditorGUILayout.Foldout(ClipArray.isExpanded, ClipArray.name);
    if(ClipArray.isExpanded)
    {
        EditorGUI.indentLevel++;

        // The field for item count
        ClipArray.arraySize = EditorGUILayout.IntField("size", ClipArray.arraySize);

        // draw item fields
        for(var i = 0; i< ClipArray.arraySize; i++)
        {
            var item = ClipArray.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i);
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(item, new GUIContent($"Element {i}");
        }

        EditorGUI.indentLevel--;
    }
    serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
}
```

I just leave it here since building these kind of stuff manually once helped me a lot to understand how the Editor works.

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone (→ there might be mistakes) but I hope the idea gets clear*